# CockroachDB and Microsoft Entity Framework

Tags: orm, frameworks, entity, cockroachdb

Does [CockroachDB](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach) work with Microsoft Entity Framework? If not which ORM would work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it should work with an external driver and we suggest using http://www.npgsql.org/.

Specifically their Entity Framework nuget package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework6.Npgsql/

If you encounter any issues, please open issue on either 
https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql or https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach

Comment: I did a sample implementation here on github https://github.com/AchoArnold/key-value-store